# configure the same servlet to different mappings and set for each a different security

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a web application that is made of a servlet, let's call it myservlet.
There are two different pattern matching the same servlet, let's call them
/patterna/* and 
/patternb/*

Assume I want to
1. attach to myservlet a chain of servlet filters, and I want this chain is different in the case I invoke the servlet with patterna and with patternb
2. in the case I invoke patternb, I want to set security for the servlet, in case I invoke patterna, I don't want any security

Is this possible? I understand that probably the limit in my application is that I want to expose the same servlet and distinguish on mappings, rather than expose two different servlets..

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to map a servlet twice - i.e. have two `<servlet>..</servlet>` tags with the same class, but different name (and different mapping). Try it.

Comment: You can safely leave the "I think" away :)

Comment: Yes, but this allows me just to use a different filter chain, not to use a different security (let's say - FORM for one, CLIENT_CERT for the other) for the two servlets...